# Massive performance degradation when upgrading PostgreSQL 9.6.5 to 10.1

Tags: postgresql, upgrade

When I upgrade my database from PostgreSQL 9.6.5 to PostgreSQL 10.1 using pg_upgrade, some of my queries involving multiple tables suffer a massive performance degradation.

Running exactly the same query on exactly the same data with exactly the same indexes in 10.1 takes around 17 seconds compared to around 0.1 second in 9.6.

Looking at the EXPLAIN plan for the query, I can see that the plan between the two versions differs a lot - especially for a couple of sub-selects.

9.6 uses indexes a lot more than 10.1. 10.1 seems to favor full table scans over the indexes - even for tables with close to 1M records.

I have verified that the indexes haven't been "lost" during the upgrade. Also if I query the tables individually, the indexes are used.

Any insights?

Thanks,
Sebastian

Comment: Did you run(VACUUM) ANALYZE on all tables?

Comment: please give us just one sample query with two plans - old and new - otherwise such post is pointless

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the `create table` statements for the tables in question (including all indexes), the queries you are using and the execution plans generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers)`**. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by doing pg_dump/pg_restore instead of pg_upgrade. Performance and query plans are back to normal.

Answer (score 1):

The output of pg_upgrade includes this:

```
...

Upgrade Complete
----------------
Optimizer statistics are not transferred by pg_upgrade so,
once you start the new server, consider running:
    ./analyze_new_cluster.sh

...
```

We found horrible performance straight after the upgrade until we ran this, lesson learned to read the output :)